# Material UI api docs out of date?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui, materialize

Is it possible that the Material UI api docs are out of date? Or is there another place to check for element preferences?

i.e. MenuList https://material-ui.com/api/menu-list/ has a property `disablePadding` to disable the top and bottom padding of the element, but there is no apparent documentation on that.

```
import { MenuList } from "@material-ui/core";
...
<MenuList disablePadding> ... </MenuList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disablePadding is from the [List](https://material-ui.com/api/list/) component.

In the Inheritance portion:

> The properties of the List component are also available.