# How to overwrite specific style in material ui component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using  component from MUI,
when I use dev tools I can see it has those styles:

```
.MuiList-padding {
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

I wish to remove the padding, but I can't get it to work,
I tried

```
  <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={closeMenu}
        styles={{MuiList:{{padding:none}}}} 
      >
        <somecomponent/>
      </Menu>
```

but no luck, any ideas?

Comment: I think you have to create a HOC and override the styles there

Comment: for that, you need to add classes attribute in Menu.
Like this classes={{ list: "menu-list"}}
then apply padding zero to menu-list.

Comment: @RajPurohit could you write me a solution for my specific case? I've read a lot of solutions like that and I didn't understand them.

Comment: Please check this codepen example https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-jzjy1

Comment: @RajPurohit thanks for your help, but the codepen doesn't work, I tried to add the CSS class just like you specified, but it did not work =\

Comment: @AlexK can you provide me your issue in codepen so solved there and you can see.

Comment: @AlexK I have updated my codepen please check it again.https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-jzjy1

Comment: @RajPurohit thank you for your help! your code pen works, but if you will inspect the menu item, the padding is still there :X

Comment: @AlexK In your question, you write that you want to remove padding from "MuiList-padding " this class that's why I only added for that.

Comment: @RajPurohit yes I wanted to remove that padding top and padding bottom, but in your code pen its still there.

Comment: @AlexK what's your material-ui version and are you using functional or class component?

Comment: @Ido the latest, and functional.

Comment: @AlexK I have updated my codepen please check https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-jzjy1

Comment: @RajPurohit Hi thank you it works, please submit your answer so I can approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `makeStyles` to define the new style for `MuiList-Padding`, and than use `useStyles` hook and `MuiListProps` prop to override that style:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  padding: {
    paddingTop: "30px",
    paddingBottom: "30px"
  }
}));

export default function SimpleMenu() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleClick = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button aria-controls="simple-menu" aria-haspopup="true" onClick={handleClick}>
        Open Menu
      </Button>
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
        MenuListProps={{
          classes: {padding: classes.padding},
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can check that working [Code Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-e5kvh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

---

Note: this answer works for material-ui V4

Comment: emm It did not work for my specific case, but thanks

Comment: @AlexK check my updated answer, I changed it to work with Menu instead of List

Comment: Anyone know how to adapt this solution to mui 5.8.1 ?

Comment: @Ryan's answer above works for mui 5.8.1 fyi!

Answer (score 8):

`List` has a `disablePadding` prop (https://material-ui.com/api/list/#props).

You can set this for `Menu` via `MenuListProps` as shown below:

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";

export default function SimpleMenu() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        aria-controls="simple-menu"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Open Menu
      </Button>
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
        MenuListProps={{
          disablePadding: true
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Menu disablePadding]

Related answers:

- [Material UI api docs out of date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54473020/material-ui-api-docs-out-of-date/54479870#54479870)
- [Remove / Override default styles from materialui components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56352255/remove-override-default-styles-from-materialui-components/56352608#56352608)

Comment: This should be the correct answer... MenuListProps={{
          disablePadding: true
        }} removes the top padding from a Menu component as intended.